# Can we convert multiple language XLIFF files to json files in angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, internationalization, translation

I wanted to write a logic in one XLIFF build for all languages to access them via json files

I was expecting a logic for the code to load multiple translations under 1 XLIFF build to run multiple translations under runtime in angular

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this.
Check this out: [translation-files](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-translation-files#change-the-source-language-file-format)

```
ng extract-i18n --format=xlf
ng extract-i18n --format=xlf2
ng extract-i18n --format=xmb
ng extract-i18n --format=json
ng extract-i18n --format=arb
```

Comment: Does this convert all the XLIFFS of mulitple languages to respective json files?